# hipMemcpy fails to copy

Tags: c++, amd-gpu, hip

I am trying to use <hip/hip_runtime.h> library, but I keep getting gibberish when exchanging data.

here is my code:

```
#include <hip/hip_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int* hipC;
    int a = 123;
    int* ap = &a;
    int* ap2 = new int;

    hipMalloc(&hipC, sizeof(int));
    hipMemcpy(hipC, ap, sizeof(int), hipMemcpyHostToDevice);
    hipMemcpy(ap2, hipC, sizeof(int), hipMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    std::cout << *ap2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

if I understand how hip malloc / memcpy works, this code should allocate space for hipC pointer, take value of a, copy it to *hipC and back to *ap2.
But when running following code it prints random ints.
There are also no errors/compiler warnings to speak of, so I'm quite stumped.
I compile code with hipcc if that matters.
thanks

Comment: Check the error codes returned from each function ?

Comment: Also [hipMemcpy](https://rocm-developer-tools.github.io/HIP/group__Memory.html#gac1a055d288302edd641c6d7416858e1e) "_...For hipMemcpy, the copy is always performed by the current device (__set by hipSetDevice__)..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten Tried printing those 3 functions, each of them printed '101'. Could not find what that means as :
hipSuccess, hipErrorMemoryAllocation, hipErrorInvalidValue each correspond to 0, 2 and 1 respectively